# RNN validation accuracy stays constant. Is this normal?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to machine learning and I'm building an RNN classifier for a problem similar to Name Entity Recognition (NER) but with only two tags.

I followed a tutorial to build the classifier, and now when fitting the model, I get a constant validation accuracy for all the epochs, and some part of me thinks this may be a mistake. Is it normal to have a constant val_accuracy ?

this is my model:

```
input = Input(shape=(66,))
word_embedding_size = 66
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_length=66)(input)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=word_embedding_size,
                            return_sequences=True,
                            dropout=0.5,
                            recurrent_dropout=0.5,
                            kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal()))(model)


model = LSTM(units=word_embedding_size * 2,
              return_sequences=True,
              dropout=0.5,
              recurrent_dropout=0.5,
              kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal())(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="sigmoid"))(model)
out = model
model = Model(input, out)

adam = k.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X, np.array(Y), batch_size=256, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3, verbose=1)
```

and this is how the epoch look

```
Epoch 1/10
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 801ms/step - loss: 0.6990 - accuracy: 0.3123 - val_loss: 0.5732 - val_accuracy: 0.9675
Epoch 2/10
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 334ms/step - loss: 0.5552 - accuracy: 0.9713 - val_loss: 0.4202 - val_accuracy: 0.9675
Epoch 3/10
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 310ms/step - loss: 0.3997 - accuracy: 0.9723 - val_loss: 0.2377 - val_accuracy: 0.9675
Epoch 4/10
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 303ms/step - loss: 0.2260 - accuracy: 0.9723 - val_loss: 0.1168 - val_accuracy: 0.9675
Epoch 5/10
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 312ms/step - loss: 0.1126 - accuracy: 0.9723 - val_loss: 0.0851 - val_accuracy: 0.9675
```

Comment: Had the same problem, turns out it was coming from the loss function. What's the format of your label `y`?

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc The format of my Y label is a list of size 500, with arrays as each of the elements of the list e.g. Y - {list:500} [array([[1.,0.],[],[]],array([[0.,1.],[],[]]...}  It has been created by:
Y = [[w[2] for w in s] for s in sentences] # a list of size 500 with 0s and 1s
Y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=Y, padding="post", value=0) # padded to size 66 as there are sequences of different sizes 
Y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=2) for i in Y] # to categorical

Comment: try changing `Y`to a list of float instead of list of array. `Y = [1.0, 0.0,...]`. According to TensorFlow doc `Binary_crossentropy` loss take a float as input. Passing an array `[1.0, .0.0]`might be the reason it has trouble learning.